# Why isn't rsync faster at copying a modified file locally?

Tags: rsync

```
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=1 bs=1048576 count=3
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
3145728 bytes transferred in 0.263337 secs (11945641 bytes/sec)
$ rsync -avz 1 2
building file list ... done
1

sent 3147373 bytes  received 42 bytes  6294830.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3145728  speedup is 1.00
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=new_prefix bs=1048576 count=3
3+0 records in
3+0 records out
3145728 bytes transferred in 0.276985 secs (11357037 bytes/sec)
$ cat 1 >> new_prefix
$ rsync -avz new_prefix 2
building file list ... done
new_prefix

sent 6294646 bytes  received 42 bytes  4196458.67 bytes/sec
total size is 6291456  speedup is 1.00
```

Why aren't I receiving any speed-up when adding a prefix to file? AFAIK, `rsync` shouldn't just yield speedups for in-place modifications.

Answer (score 0):

So what you're doing is:

1. Use rsync to copy a local file `1` to `2`.
2. Make a new file `new_prefix` that is the same as `1` but has some more data inserted at the start.
3. Copy `new_prefix` on top of 2.

Think about what rsync has to do, to execute step 3.

Remember there is no OS interface to say "insert data at the start of a file": the only option is to rewrite the entire file `2`. So rsync has to read the entire `new_prefix` file, and then write the entire `2`. The IO is the limiting factor and there's no magic way around it.

If file 2 was remote, then librsync can make use of the similarity to send less network traffic and probably will show a speedup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, poolie. So this was a contrived example to test the speedup thus running it locally. I am aware that a file can't be prepended OS-wise, but I was assuming that `rsync` would be able to reuse its tail part locally without sending it over "network" a second time when rebuilding `2`. I assume `rsync` doesn't handle this case?

Comment: When I execute rsync to copy two files locally it actually executes three rsync processes. I assume the first one orchestrates the other two. Based on their open files (see "socket" in lsof output in gist below) they use a UNIX socket for local transfers. That's what I meant by "network" since I assume that `rsync` uses the same protocol for interhost communication as for intrahost. See https://gist.github.com/JensRantil/f0bb27c3f08076e9ce61. Let me know if I am wrong.